# Not able to replicate the path as shown in tutorials

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

I am not able to replicate this image as shown in this tutorial.

> Keep focusing on your red path and pick the Direct Selection Tool (A). Select the eleven anchor points highlighted in the first image, simply hit the Delete button from your keyboard and you should end up with the seven red paths as shown in the second image.

This is the image from the tutorial:

[image]

This is my attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your path looks correct. But you have either a custom width profile or a custom brush set. Both are shown in the top bar when your path is selected.

Make sure your profile is set to "Uniform" and brush is set the "Basic".

It looks like you also have a fill set and a white stroke. Remove the fill and set the stroke to red, as I have done here:

[image]

Comment: also it looks like the shape has a fill color, when it should have only the stroke

Comment: Ah yes! Not sure how I missed that. I was tired :)